# How to copy a BitmapCacheBrush to a Rectangle Fill

Tags: wpf, fill

How can I copy a BitmapCacheBrush to the Fill of a Rectangle?

I don't want to use binding as that is preventing me from freezing. I somehow need to 'copy' or 'clone' the BitmapCacheBrush but Clone and CloneCurrentValue are both cloning the Binding as well.

I want to use BitmapCacheBrush as it's producing the best results with animation. Also it doesn't trigger re-rendering.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?